# Can I have delcaration like ** vector < pair <int ,vector < int >> > vec** in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stdvector, std-pair

Can I declare a vector like  `vector < pair < int ,vector < int > > >vec` in C++ ?

Actually, I want to make a 2-D vector(in the form of a pair) where 1st element of pair corresponds to some key(like `2 ,3 ,4` ) and 2nd element will hold a vector .
I am making pair because I want to sort the 2-D vector according to the key(1st element othe of the `pair < int ,vector < int >`).

If yes, then How to fetch the value stored from each row?

I have written code but I know its not correct. Please help and also how help with the  **sort()** function in the code.

```
/*  Box Stacking */

bool comp(pair<int,vector<int> >a,pair<int,vector<int> >b)   // sort ???
{
   return (a.first > b.first);
}

int maxHeight(int height[], int width[], int length[], int n)
{
   vector<pair<int,vector<int> > >vec;   // IS THIS DECLARATION CORRECT 
   vector<int> v;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      v.push_back(height[i]);
      v.push_back(width[i]);
      v.push_back(length[i]);

      do
      {
         vec.push_back({(v[0]*v[1]),v});
      }while(next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()));
      v.clear();
    }

    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),comp);
    int dp[n+2];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       dp[i] = vec[i].second.[2];   // HERE HOW TO GET THE ELEMENT
    }                              //( I am tryinh to access the 2nd index element from each row)
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
           if(vec[i].second.[0]<vec[j].second.[0] &&              // similar problem here
           vec[i].second.[1]<vec[j].second.[1]  && dp[i] < dp[j] + 1)
           {
               dp[i] = dp[j] + 1;
           }
        }
    }

    int maxi = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    maxi = max(maxi,dp[i]);

    return maxi;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `std::map`(if key s are unique) or `std::multimap` (key are not unique)?

Comment: `.[2]` is not valud syntax on any C++ object.

Comment: Not unique because the key value is equal to (vec[0]*vec[1]) i.,e its a **base area** according to the problem .

Comment: I solved this problem using Structure but actually I m practicing for the STL so I came up with only .
Can you help with the fetching the row element in above code .[2] is wrong , If Help to corrrect it

Comment: @failure_14 you need to make all of `vec[i].second.[2]` to `vec[i].second[2]`. Without the *dot*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I have delcaration like `vector < pair <int ,vector < int >> > vec` in C++?

Yes, you can. Nothing wrong in this.

Regarding accessing the elements in the value-array, here,

```
std::pair<int, std::vector<int> >
          key,   vector_array
```

You have for each key associated with a vector array. Accessing an array element with `operator[]` would be `array[array_index]` (or using a range based for loop or an iterator loop)

This is the `second` of the `std::par`. i,e. `.second[array_index]`.

Since you have an array of above mentioned: `vec[index_pair_array].second[array_index]` would be the appropriate way of accessing each element in this 2D array.

Then you need this:

```
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      dp[i] = vec[i].second[2];   
   }                              
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
       {
           if(vec[i].second[0] < vec[j].second[0] &&              // similar problem here
              vec[i].second[1] < vec[j].second[1]  && dp[i] < dp[j] + 1)
              {
                  dp[i] = dp[j] + 1;
              }
       }
   }
```

Comment: @failure_14 And for finding the max of an array,(`maxi = max(maxi,dp[i]);`), you can use [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)